# how to get current user data only in laravel

Tags: laravel

i am working on laravel and want to get only login user data but when i change code it give error in my view

```
public function index(){
        $users = User::all();//Auth::user();//
        //dd($users);
        return view ('profile.index',compact('users'));
    }
```

this is the code that give output and show all user data 
 when i change the code the error it give me no output
[this is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JsnD.jpg)

this is view i am using

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="container" >
  <h2>Basic Details<h2>
  <form>
    @foreach($users as $user)
<image  src=" {{$user['image']}}" class="img-circle">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <h4>Name:</h4>
      <input type="text" value="{{$user['name']}}" class="form-control" id="text" name="text" 
      readonly="true">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
      <h4 for="Email">Email:</h4>
      <input type="email" value="{{$user['email']}}" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" 
      readonly="true">
    </div>
     @endforeach
  </form>
```

Comment: You can't use the same code because user;all returns a collection of user objects where as auth()->user() gives an object

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code and, as @pseudoanime commented, you can't directly interchange the single user case vs. all users because of the returned data types. However, if you REALLY want to do this, you could change things up so that both situations return a collection, as shown below:

```
public function index(){
    $users = collect(Auth::user());
    return view ('profile.index',compact('users'));
}
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do this rather than simply returning a different view, but I'll leave that up to you. Please note that I would suggest re-evaluating your problem and taking a different approach, as it makes no sense to loop through a collection you will know only has a single member.

Additionally, you should note that you are not accessing the user model properly. You are using array syntax in the view (for example, $user['email']) when you should be using object syntax ($user->email). There are other issues with the code that may still cause issues, but this is the most obvious problem I see.

Comment: Using `Auth::user()` in conjunction with `User::where(...)->get();` is redundant and inefficient. I see what you're suggesting, but I wouldn't recommend that approach. You could just use `collect(Auth::user());` though.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't recommend this either. It's fixing a bigger problem with a pointless (and poorly coded) bandaid. However, I am just giving him a solution that will solve what he's looking to do, but honestly the whole endeavor seems puzzling. That said, your approach looks a little nicer even if it's doing roughly the same thing. So i'll update my response.

Comment: Agreed. I was in the process of writing a comment on the main question before realizing that it essentially was rephrasing your answer, so I figured I'd add the slightly more optimized approach as a comment here. Honestly, they just need to remove the loop, change `$users` to `$user`, and `compact("users")` to `compact("user")` and everything should work fine.